# Network share: How to set one subdir invisible to users

Tags: linux, samba

I denied access to one subdir for the windows users, but this subdir remains visible. Could it possible hide it based on permission model?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `smb.conf`:

```
veto files = mysubdir
```

Also see the [documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#VETOFILES).

Comment: the veto works.  I have simple share accessed by predefined  user and  few localnet machines uses the same user login credentials  i'm not familiar with samba and setfacl unix model. so i still looking for tutorial how to set  up it in rightway